# calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler not returning with error or response

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, mkdirection

I'm calling the `calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler` method from `MKDirections`, but the completion handler is never called. Not even with an error. And since the request is made in the main thread, the entire application gets stuck. I ensure that the directionRequest has source and destination and both locations are not nil. Someone have experienced the same?

```
[directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {


    if (error) {

        NSLog(@"%@", error);

    }else{

        // Deal with the response

    }

}];
```

Comment: The most likely cause for the completion handler not being called is if the calculate method isn't called.  The most likely cause for that is `directions == nil`.

Comment: Thats the point, directions is not nil. The `MKDirectionRequest` that i am using to instantiate the directions is not nil either. I have no idea whats is happening.